# Hang issue in java application

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, threadpool, freeze

Below is the thread dump sneapet. App is getting hang after running some days.
Suspecting

- **java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0** , Might it be root issue?

---

Attaching to process ID 14226, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.121-b13
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

```
Thread 25940: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78, line=2078 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=124, line=1093 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1, line=809 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Compiled frame)


Thread 15960: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Compiled frame)


Thread 15959: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=8, line=116 (Compiled frame)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) @bci=117, line=171 (Compiled frame)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=11, line=141 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer() @bci=71, line=160 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer() @bci=1, line=84 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer) @bci=130, line=273 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer.readLine(org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer) @bci=5, line=122 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(org.apache.http.io.SessionInputBuffer) @bci=16, line=140 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(org.apache.http.io.SessionInputBuffer) @bci=2, line=57 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse() @bci=38, line=261 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader() @bci=8, line=283 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader() @bci=1, line=259 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader() @bci=6, line=209 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(org.apache.http.HttpRequest, org.apache.http.HttpClientConnection, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=41, line=272 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(org.apache.http.HttpRequest, org.apache.http.HttpClientConnection, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=39, line=124 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(org.apache.http.impl.client.RoutedRequest, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=198, line=686 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost, org.apache.http.HttpRequest, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=578, line=488 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(org.apache.http.HttpHost, org.apache.http.HttpRequest, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=362, line=884 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=14, line=82 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=3, line=55 (Compiled frame)
 - org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders, byte[]) @bci=56, line=89 (Compiled frame)
 - org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders) @bci=27, line=48 (Compiled frame)
 - org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute() @bci=9, line=53 (Compiled frame)
 - org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(java.net.URI, org.springframework.http.HttpMethod, org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback, org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor) @bci=37, line=652 (Compiled frame)
 - org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(java.lang.String, org.springframework.http.HttpMethod, org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback, org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor, java.util.Map) @bci=21, line=621 (Compiled frame)
 - org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(java.lang.String, org.springframework.http.HttpMethod, org.springframework.http.HttpEntity, java.lang.Class, java.util.Map) @bci=26, line=540 (Compiled frame)
 - com.kodiak.couchservice.frameworks.querymgr.workers.KnPutDocWorker.executeRequest() @bci=375, line=159 (Compiled frame)
 - com.kodiak.couchservice.frameworks.querymgr.workers.KnPutDocWorker.run() @bci=37, line=83 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1142 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Compiled frame)


Thread 15507: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15506: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15505: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15504: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(int, long) @bci=139, line=1037 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(int, long) @bci=25, line=1328 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=10, line=277 (Compiled frame)
 - com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(rx.Observable, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=32, line=72 (Compiled frame)
 - com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.get(java.lang.String, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=17, line=128 (Compiled frame)
 - com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.get(java.lang.String) @bci=9, line=123 (Compiled frame)
 - com.kodiak.microservices.common.couchsdk.KnCBSdkHelper.getDocument(java.lang.String) @bci=9, line=120 (Compiled frame)
 - com.kodiak.microservices.common.task.KnDocumentBaseTask.getDocumentSync() @bci=59, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - com.kodiak.microservices.location.task.KnLocationHistoryTask.getDocumentSync() @bci=6, line=121 (Compiled frame)
 - com.kodiak.microservices.location.cleintEvents.KnLocationPublishEventTask.processHistoryDoc() @bci=22, line=158 (Compiled frame)
 - com.kodiak.microservices.location.cleintEvents.KnLocationPublishEventTask.intiateLocationDocUpdateTask(com.kodiak.microservices.location.dto.KnLocation) @bci=163, line=124 (Compiled frame)
 - com.kodiak.microservices.location.cleintEvents.KnLocationPublishEventTask.handleUpdateLocationDocument(com.kodiak.microservices.location.dto.KnLocation) @bci=81, line=96 (Compiled frame)
 - com.kodiak.microservices.location.cleintEvents.KnLocationPublishEventTask.run() @bci=232, line=58 (Compiled frame)
 - com.kodiak.AppPlatform.dto.BaseDocuments.<init>() @bci=1, line=13 (Compiled frame)
 - com.kodiak.microservices.common.dto.userNotify.KnUserActivation.<init>() @bci=1, line=12 (Compiled frame)
 - com.kodiak.microservices.location.messaging.KnLocRMQMsgProcessor.run() @bci=557, line=105 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1142 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15503: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15502: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15501: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15500: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15499: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15498: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15497: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78, line=2078 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=124, line=1093 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1, line=809 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15496: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=8, line=116 (Compiled frame)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) @bci=117, line=171 (Compiled frame)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=11, line=141 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill() @bci=214, line=246 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.read() @bci=12, line=265 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte() @bci=4, line=288 (Compiled frame)
 - com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(java.io.DataInputStream) @bci=1, line=91 (Compiled frame)
 - com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame() @bci=11, line=164 (Compiled frame)
 - com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run() @bci=17, line=580 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15495: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15494: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78, line=2078 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=124, line=1093 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1, line=809 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15493: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=8, line=116 (Compiled frame)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) @bci=117, line=171 (Compiled frame)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=11, line=141 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill() @bci=214, line=246 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.read() @bci=12, line=265 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte() @bci=4, line=288 (Compiled frame)
 - com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(java.io.DataInputStream) @bci=1, line=91 (Compiled frame)
 - com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame() @bci=11, line=164 (Compiled frame)
 - com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run() @bci=17, line=580 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15492: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78, line=2078 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=124, line=1093 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1, line=809 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15491: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78, line=2078 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=124, line=1093 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1, line=809 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15490: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78, line=2078 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=124, line=1093 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1, line=809 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15489: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78, line=2078 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=124, line=1093 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1, line=809 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15488: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=24, line=1081 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1, line=809 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15483: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.ThreadDeathWatcher$Watcher.run() @bci=19, line=152 (Compiled frame)
 - com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run() @bci=4, line=144 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 15367: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(long, int, long, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(long) @bci=18, line=269 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(long) @bci=28, line=93 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(long) @bci=37, line=86 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(long
```

---

**EDIT** (taken from comments)

Read Time out and connection timeout we are providing. However I/O exception usually comes on connection lost. But on hang situation we dont't get any exception also.

```
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));

PoolingClientConnectionManager httpConnectionManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry);
httpConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(500);
httpConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(200);

DefaultHt‌​tpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpConnectionManager);
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCU‌​LAR_REDIRECTS, true);

requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(30000);
requestFactory.setReadTimeout(30000);

knlogger.info(methodname,"Created requestFactory");
```

Comment: Could you please format the text a bit

Answer (score 2):

While it is impossible to tell this for sure what is happening with the amount of information we have right now I can assume one possible reason for app to "hang":

You are using blocking I/O. The code is waiting for next data packet at several threads (those at `socketRead0`). This may be normal but most probably the network connection was lost (e.g. network interruption on router, etc.). Since transport layer is completely a responsibility of underlying OS the app may not be notified about connection interruption for a long time (e.g. until OS will fail to send a keepalive message several times to recepient when keepalive configured) or until app itself will try to send the data over the same socket.

To prevent this happening you should think of one of the following solutions:

- Setting a read timeout (by default JVM classes are configured to "no timeout") and reconnecting after timeout
- Enabling keep alive for connection (if possible). How fast connection loss is detected depends on protocol settings in OS.
- Having systems exchanging the heartbeats - e.g. 3 missed heartbeats mean connection is lost.

In any case you should be ready to handle the connection exception and try to reconnect.

Comment: Read Time out and connection timeout we are providing. However I/O exception usually comes on connection lost. But  on hang situation we dont't get any exception also. Is there any issue with pool size and memory balancing?

Comment: Sorry for providing code in two comments as limited characters ;)                  SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
  schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
  schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
  PoolingClientConnectionManager httpConnectionManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry);
  httpConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(500);
  httpConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(200);DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpConnectionManager);

Comment: httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);
  requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
  requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(30000);
  requestFactory.setReadTimeout(30000);
  knlogger.info(methodname,"Created requestFactory");

Comment: In thread 15959 you are using RestTemplate.exchange() are you sure this one is using your socket configuration? This seem to be a background worker stuck at reading.

Comment: Your configuration seem to be fine. You should really try to log the socket options in your worker for debug purposes. Also you may enable TCP keepalive on your socket.

Comment: Maksimovich,the main problem is that we don't know how to produce this issue. sometime it work fine for the month but sometimes it hung within couple of days. Enabling debug is not good in live server, which might help a lot. With same network configuration,other app is not having any problem. But only with our app,we are facing issue. Now I think I should go for ur suggestions to enable the debug socket options log in  worker.

Comment: The root cause of this issue was creating the thread pool for every request, which was a coding issue. BTW thanks, Maks.